# Insert text after a number of lines

Tags: unix

I have a file which contains the word  MODEL every 36125 lines. I would like to add the following lines before every occurrence of "MODEL" word

```
REMARK    GENERATED BY TRJCONV
TITLE     DRG t= 980.00000
REMARK    THIS IS A SIMULATION BOX
CRYST1   71.471   71.471   71.471  90.00  90.00  90.00 P 1           1
```

After Jim's answer I did the following

```
add='REMARK    GENERATED BY TRJCONV
TITLE     DRG t= 980.00000
REMARK    THIS IS A SIMULATION BOX
CRYST1   71.471   71.471   71.471  90.00  90.00  90.00 P 1           1
'

awk -v n=8 -v s="$add" 'NR == n {print s} {print}' file > newfile
```

but this gives me the following error

```
awk: newline in string REMARK    GENERATED ... at source line 1
```

Comment: So? What is the question? What have you tried where you fail? And what is the problem with your attempt?

Comment: I have tried grep command but i don't know the syntax to replace lines. Actually I didn't try almost anything because I don't know what to do! I have read several solutions with sed command but they didn't work.

Comment: `grep` only filters, it does not replace. Have a look at `sed` or `awk`. Start by looking at their man pages.

Comment: Look at `sed` or Awk instead. `grep` has no facility for replacement. This is fairly certain to be a duplicate; google for `NR` and "modulus".

Comment: As I said I have tried with see some solutions of other people but didn't help much. Reading the manual would be a good start but I'd prefer an opinion of an expert to this because it would save me a lot of time which I need to post process other resuts

Comment: Oh, add Awk to the Google query. SO doesn't like Google links much but surely you can take it from here.

Comment: See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist

Comment: I will try to google Awk and NR thanks. At your last post iam not sure that i understand what you wrote. Thanks

Comment: is `MODEL` the only word on the line? ELSE are you sure that the word `MODEL` never appears except where you need to add the extra lines? Consider adding this information to your question above, rather than carrying on extended conversations in comments. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
add="REMARK    GENERATED BY TRJCONV
TITLE     DRG t= 980.00000
REMARK    THIS IS A SIMULATION BOX
CRYST1   71.471   71.471   71.471  90.00  90.00  90.00 P 1           1
"

awk -v var="$add" 'NR>1 && NR%36125==0 {print add} {print $0}' oldfile > newfile
```

This runs on a vanilla awk - just tested it:

```
rem1="REMARK    GENERATED BY TRJCONV"
rem2="TITLE     DRG t= 980.00000"
rem3="REMARK    THIS IS A SIMULATION BOX"
rem4="CRYST1   71.471   71.471   71.471  90.00  90.00  90.00 P 1           1"

nawk -v var1="$rem1" \
     -v var2="$rem2" \
     -v var3="$rem3" \
     -v var4="$rem4" \
    'NR>1 && NR%36125==0 {print var1; print var2; print var3; print var4} 
      {print $0}' oldfile > newfile
```

This was my problem using a weird variant of awk originally - sorry.

Comment: it comes with the error
awk: newline in string REMARK    GENERATED ... at source line 1